# AngularJs dependency injection related to $http

Tags: angularjs

While writing the above code in `AngularJs`, I am getting an error :

```
Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider
Unknown provider: $http
```

I believe the reason might be while injecting `$http` through the `serviceProvider` which in my case is `httpServiceProviderFunction.$inject = ["$http"];`. I would appreciate if anyone could help me understand these two questions:

1) Although I have injected the `$http` in the `httpServiceProviderFunction`. Why am I getting the above error? 
2)Is there any way I can inject `$http` in the `service` directly without injecting in `serviceProvider`? In my example, it corresponds to this line:

```
 function httpService(url, $http) {.....}
```

The code snippet can be found below:

```js
(function() {
  angular.module("httpServiceApp", []).controller("httpServiceController", httpServiceControllerFunction).provider("httpService", httpServiceProviderFunction).config(configObj);
  configObj.$inject = ["httpServiceProvider"]

  function configObj(httpServiceProvider) {
    httpServiceProvider.configuration.baseUrl = "http://davids-restaurant.herokuapp.com/categories.json";
  }
  httpServiceProviderFunction.$inject = ["$http"];

  function httpServiceProviderFunction($http) {
    var provider = this;
    provider.configuration = {
      baseUrl: "http://davids-restaurant.herokuapp.com/categories.json"
    }
    provider.$get = function() {
      var service = new httpService(provider.configuration.baseUrl, $http);
      return service;
    }
  }

  function httpService(url, $http) {
    var service = this;
    service.menuCategories = function() {
      var response = $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: url
      });
      return response;
    }
  }
  httpServiceControllerFunction.$inject = ["httpService"]

  function httpServiceControllerFunction(httpService) {
    var service = httpService;
    var controller = this;
    var promise = service.menuCategories();
    promise.then(function(response) {
      controller.categories = response.data;
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error occured", error);
    })
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="httpServiceApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="First Angular App">
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, Javascript, AngularJs">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app1.js"></script>
  <title>HTTP service in AngularJs</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="httpServiceController as controller">
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="items in controller.categories">({{items.short_name}}){{items.name}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you for your time. I appreciate your help.